# Product Sans is turning numbers into circles

Tags: fonts, font-family

I'm using Product Sans bold as font and when I write (3) it transforms into [image]
Is there a way to fix this witout having to change the font?
Thank you

Comment: Hi ! It shouldn't : https://fontsfree.net/product-sans-bold-font-download.html?preview=123456789 So, how can we reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Hi, https://befonts.com/product-sans-font.html in this you can see the same problem I have

Comment: Hello WebDev ! No I don't, sorry for that : https://i.imgur.com/iKigx8d.png

Comment: Hello, you have to put (1) , (2) not only numbers

Comment: Oh ! Sorry I misunderstood your question and your comment :) It seems this font has shortcuts inside and you face one of them. Some others are `google_logo` and `google_G` for example.